# Implementing Multiple ActionListeners in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, calculator

I am having trouble implementing multiple action listeners in my Java program. The program is a calculator that does basic functions with a basic GUI. From my research I have noticed that action listeners should go into different classes. I have comprised my program of four action listeners but I keep getting a terrible amount of errors every time I run my program along with warnings for each action listener saying "The serializable class ClearListener does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long" Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class GUICalc extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton[] numberButtons;
    JButton[] upButtons;

    JTextField field;
    double num1;

    double num2;

    double ans; 
    int op;

    DigitalListener listener1 = new DigitalListener();
    OperatorListener listener2 = new OperatorListener();
    ClearListener listerner3 = new ClearListener();
    EqualsListener listerner4 = new EqualsListener();

    // 0 = gridx 1 gridy 2 gridwidth 3 gridheight
    private int[][] numConstraints = new int[][] {
            {0, 4, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1},
            {2, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 2, 1, 1},
            {1, 2, 1, 1},
            {2, 2, 1, 1},
            {0, 3, 1, 1},
            {1, 3, 1, 1},
            {2, 3, 1, 1},
    };

    private int[][] upConstraints = new int[][] {
            {1, 4, 1, 1},
            {3, 4, 1, 1},
            {3, 3, 1, 1},
            {3, 2, 1, 1},
            {3, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 5, 4, 1},
            {2, 4, 1, 1},
    };

    public GUICalc() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(666, 666)); //width & heigth

        GridBagLayout layout; // used to be private
        GridBagConstraints gbc; // used to be private

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        layout.columnWidths = new int[] {60, 60, 60, 60};
        layout.rowHeights = new int[] {60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60};
        setLayout(layout);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            numberButtons = new JButton[10];

            numberButtons[0] = new JButton("0");
            numberButtons[1] = new JButton("1");
            numberButtons[2] = new JButton("2");
            numberButtons[3] = new JButton("3");
            numberButtons[4] = new JButton("4");
            numberButtons[5] = new JButton("5");
            numberButtons[6] = new JButton("6");
            numberButtons[7] = new JButton("7");
            numberButtons[8] = new JButton("8");
            numberButtons[9] = new JButton("9");

            for(int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++){
                gbc.gridx = numConstraints[i][0];
                gbc.gridy = numConstraints[i][1];
                gbc.gridwidth = numConstraints[i][2];
                gbc.gridheight = numConstraints[1][3];
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2); 
                numberButtons[i].addActionListener(listener1);
                add(numberButtons[i], gbc);
                }

        upButtons = new JButton[7];

        upButtons[0] = new JButton(".");
        upButtons[1] = new JButton("/");
        upButtons[2] = new JButton("*");
        upButtons[3] = new JButton("-");
        upButtons[4] = new JButton("+");
        upButtons[5] = new JButton("=");
        upButtons[6] = new JButton("C");

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[0][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[0][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[0][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[0].addActionListener(listener2);
            add(upButtons[0], gbc); 

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[1][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[1][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[1][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[1].addActionListener(listener2);
            add(upButtons[1], gbc); 

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[2][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[2][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[2][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[2].addActionListener(listener2);
            add(upButtons[2], gbc); 

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[3][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[3][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[3][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[3].addActionListener(listener2);
            add(upButtons[3], gbc); 

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[4][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[4][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[4][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[4].addActionListener(listener2);
            add(upButtons[4], gbc); 

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[5][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[5][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[5][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[5].addActionListener(listerner4);
            add(upButtons[5], gbc); 

            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[6][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[6][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[6][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[6].addActionListener(listerner3);
            add(upButtons[6], gbc);

        field = new JTextField();
        field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        field.setEditable(false);
        field.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 24));
        field.setText(null);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        add(field, gbc);

    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new GUICalc(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);     

    }

}

class DigitalListener extends GUICalc implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[0]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 0);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[1]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 1);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[2]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 2);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[3]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 3);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[4]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 4);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[5]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 5);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[6]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 6);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[7]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 7);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[8]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 8);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[9]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 9);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == upButtons[0] && !field.getText().contains(".")) {
                field.setText(field.getText() + ".");
            }
    }
}

class OperatorListener extends GUICalc implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[1]) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 4;
            field.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[2]) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 3;
            field.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[3]) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 2;
            field.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[4]) {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 1;
            field.setText("");
        }
    }
}

class ClearListener extends GUICalc implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[6]) {
            field.setText("0.0");
        }
    }
}

class EqualsListener extends GUICalc implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[5]) {
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());

            if(op == 1){
                ans = num1 + num2;
            } else if(op == 2){
                ans = num1 - num2;

            } else if(op == 3){
                ans = num1 * num2;
            } else if(op == 4){
                ans = num1 / num2;
            } 

            op = 0;
            field.setText("" + ans);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `JButton.setActionCommand(String)` to send a message to your action listener. In actionPerformed, use `if (e.getActionCommand().equals(String))` to check for the message. I would recommend that you avoid using many actionListeners unless you intend to add and remove them depending on settings. The serialUID issue suggests that you extended JFrame/a swing component with ClearListener and/or GUICalc. Create a field; `private final long serialUID = 1L`. I'm working off memory, so there will be typos, but the general process is correct.

Comment: `The serializable class ClearListener does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long` This is a warning not error.

Comment: Yes, I apologize I have changed the the text to say warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Do in this way:

```
class OperatorListener implements ActionListener {

   private GUICalc guiCalc;
   public OperatorListener(GUICalc guiCalc){
       this.guiCalc=guiCalc;
   }
   // use guiCalc to refer the values
   ...
 }
```

and in `GUICalc.java`

```
OperatorListener listener2 = new OperatorListener(this);
```

Do same thing for all type of your custom listener.

---

**You have created a  cyclic dependencies between objects.**

`GUICalc` contains `OperatorListener`

```
public class GUICalc extends JPanel {
   ...

   OperatorListener listener2 = new OperatorListener();
   ...
```

}

`OperatorListener` is extending `GUICalc` class

```
class OperatorListener extends GUICalc implements ActionListener {...}
```

Now whenever `GUICalc` super class object is going to construct it tries to create the dependencies sub-class objects such as `OperatorListener` but now sub-class object can't be constructed until and unless super-class object is created.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! for some reason my decimal button has now stopped working but I am sure that will be a quick fix!

Comment: Let me try to look into it. I'll come back.

Comment: O now I figured it out, it was in the wrong action listener. Completely my bad.

Comment: ooo ok, thanks I was just about to ask why I didn't have to use "extends GUICalc". Everything is working perfectly! thank you very much for your time and the help!

Answer (score 1):

Although the first answer was already accepted, some hints:

The recommendation that "action listeners should be in different classes" is correct. However, this does not mean that you should arbitrarily combine several ActionListeners into one class. While this is possible and may be feasible in some cases, there are solutions that are more appropriate for use-cases like yours.

This could help you to simplify your code a little. (If I had to clean it up, I'd start with the GridBagLayout and these `numConstraints` arrays - I think these are horrible - but this is a different story...). Particularly, you could create a method that creates an anonymous `ActionListener` like this:

```
private ActionListener createActionListener(final String string)
{
    return new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            field.setText(field.getText() + string);
        }
    };
}
```

Then you could create instances of these listeners and add them to the buttons:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++)
{ 
    ...
    numberButtons[i].addActionListener(
        createActionListener(String.valueOf(i)));
}
```

(Note that then you might not even have to store the `numberButtons` array as an instance variable in the best case...)

A similar concept could be applied to the operation-buttons. In general, I consider it as a good practice to use anonymous listeners to just "connect" a particular method call to one button, roughly like this:

```
someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

For many cases, it is even more beneficial to use `Action`s (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html ), but this is at least conceptually similar, in contrast to having an `ActionListener` that examines the event source or the action command.

Comment: Thank you. I am fairly new to Java programming and having experienced programmers explain things like this helps immensely.